# Event Tracking Banner on Analytics

Tags: jquery, html, events, google-analytics, tracking

I've been searching in a lot of forums and trying to figure out how to implement event tracking on a banner in my site, but everything I'm trying is not working properly.
This is the code on my banner right now

```
<a onClick=”ga(‘send’, ‘event’, ‘Banner’, ‘Click’, ‘Security Leaders’);” target="_blank" href="http://www.congressosecurityleaders.com.br/#!porto-alegre/luktq"> 
    <img src="http://www.decisionreport.com.br/img/banner/POA728x90_2016.gif" alt="Security Leaders 2016 |  Porto Alegre" title="Inscreva-se!">
</a>
```